# Parse HTML and isolate the integer found after a known prefix of qualifying tags with id attributes

Tags: php, arrays, string, html-parsing, text-extraction

Simply put,

I have a string with a prefix "msg" followed by some numbers that serve as the ID for a list item

e.g.

```
<li id="msg1"></li>..............<li id="msg1234567890"></li>
```

What is the most efficient way to grab just the numbers?

In VB, I'd do the following:

```
str = "msg1"
str = right(str,len(str)-3)
```

How would I do something similar (or more efficient) in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the same in php (using [substr](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php)):

```
$str = "msg1";
$str = substr($str,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use preg:

```
preg_match_all('%<li id="msg(\d+)"></li>%i', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: I think it's better to use this method, with regex, because if you have an id with 4 letters at the beginning, the other method with substr won't work properly

Answer (score 0):

substr( $string, 3 );

See  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

When parsing valid HTML, use an HTML parser.

Below demonstrates how to use DomDocument and an XPath query to specifically target `li` elements with `msg` prefixed `id` values, then uses `sscanf()` to isolate the integer after `msg` (cast as an integer) before being pushed into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/h3VI3))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<ul>
    <li id="msg1"></li>
    <li id="msg1234567890"></li>
</ul>
HTML;

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate("//li[starts-with(@id, 'msg')]/@id") as $id) {
    sscanf($id->nodeValue, 'msg%d', $result[]);
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 1234567890,
)
```